# Transform a pandas serie of collections.counter objects into a many columns of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, counter, pos-tagger

i have a serie of collection.counter objects in each row. Like this:

```
0       {'PRP$': 1, 'NNS': 1, 'VBP': 1, 'DT': 3, 'NN':...
1                   {'JJS': 1, 'NN': 4, 'IN': 1, 'JJ': 1}
2       {'DT': 2, 'NNS': 3, 'VBD': 1, 'TO': 1, 'VB': 1...
3          {'CD': 2, 'NNS': 3, 'JJ': 1, 'NN': 2, 'IN': 1}
4       {'RB': 1, 'VBN': 1, 'VBD': 1, 'DT': 2, 'NN': 4...
                              ...                        
7602    {'DT': 2, 'NN': 4, 'RB': 2, 'VBD': 1, 'CC': 1,...
7603    {'NNS': 2, 'VBP': 1, 'DT': 3, 'NN': 6, 'VBZ': ...
7604    {'NNS': 5, 'VBN': 2, 'IN': 1, 'NN': 4, 'JJ': 1...
7605    {'IN': 4, 'DT': 2, 'JJ': 2, 'NN': 5, 'VBP': 2,...
7606       {'JJ': 2, 'NN': 8, 'NNS': 2, 'CD': 1, 'IN': 2}
```

And i want to create new columns in my pandas dataframe with something like this:

```
re-arranged_data = {'PRP$':[1,2,3...1,0],
            'NN':[1,1,1,0,...1],
            'DT':[0,0,0,0,1000],
             ...
           }
```

I don't know how to make this step and also don't know how to add the re-arranged_data as new columns.

Any help?

Comment: pd.DataFrame(s.tolist())

Answer (score 4):

Use `df.from_records()`.

Example code is here.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
a = Counter({'PRP$':1, 'NNS':1})
b = Counter({'JJS':2, 'NNS': 3})

A = pd.Series([a, b])

pd.DataFrame.from_records(A, columns = A.sum().keys())
```

Comment: excelent, i should create this columns into a dataframe that already exist, Can i do it with merge and the default index, or not?

Comment: If your dataframe has unique index (not 0, 1, 2, ...), the answer is no. Otherwise, the answer is yes. Anyway, in this case, using concat instead of merge is better choice because implicit index (i.e., location index) is the same.

Comment: If this answer is helpful, please accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually append it into the dataframe
import pandas as pd
import collections

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=["PRP", "NN" ....])
dataframe.append(collection.counter)